# Eclipse Ganymede not validating tag files properly

Tags: eclipse, jsp, ganymede, tagfile

When editing foo.tag with a line like:

`<h1>Header</h1>`

it says on the <h1>: "Unknown tag (h1)"

it says on the </h1>: "Error"

This only happens in tag files, not JSPs.

Ayudame?

Comment: If you do want to update to WTP3.1, I believe you need to get Galileo (3.5) , and not Ganymede (3.4). You still can try to update just WTP by adding its update site (http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/), but I am not sure it can work with 3.4.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I am working with Google App Engine, which recommends sticking with 3.4, so I guess I will have to endure this bug awhile longer yet.

Comment: GAE just now supports Eclipse 3.5.  I downloaded it, and the errors went away.  The warning ("Unknown tag (h1)") is still there!  Improved but not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of WTP are you using?

This seems to have been noticed in the [webtool mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg17110.html), referring to the bug [**204990**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=204990).
This has been fixed in WTP3.1 (jst.jsp3.1.1) a month ago.

Comment: I am using 3.0.4, which is Ganymede SR2 out of the box.  I'll try updating WTP.  Thanks!

Comment: Er .. okay, how do I get 3.1.1?  I clicked on "update" in Eclipse, and it felt 3.0.4 needed no updating.

Comment: It's not out yet.  It will be part of Galileo SR1.  See http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=gchs7nm4nvpm837469ddj9tjlk%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/New_York