# Turn off selected HTML errors in aptana

Tags: html, eclipse, aptana

Is there any way to achieve that in Aptana (v3.0)? I'm posting this because [solution for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246450/turn-off-selected-html-errors-in-eclipse) does not work in Aptana.

It's annoying that Aptana(Eclipse) returns html errors on partial html code. It's  obvious that today noone has full page in one file.

It seems that it's [know bug](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2948?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs) and it's going to be fixed in 3.0.5. Is there anything I can do to turn off those annoying warining before 3.0.5 will be released?

Comment: Someone wants to close my question. Why mark this as offtopic if [given example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246450/turn-off-selected-html-errors-in-eclipse) is here safe and sound? Do you think that Aptana does not relate to programming? If you do, why there are tags named `aptana`, `ecpise`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [add custom error message filters](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Adding+custom+error+message+filters+to+the+Problems+View) or [turn off validation for the specific language all together](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Enabling+and+disabling+validation).